# The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have checked over this several times. The column count matches yet I keep getting an error saying the fetch into statement does not match the count

```
declare cur_range CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
GroupID,
OddEven,
RangeLow,
RangeHigh
PostCode1,
PostCode2,
ID,
OldPrimaryID,
ThFareID
FROM tmpNewPrimaryRange;    

OPEN cur_range

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_range
into
 @cur_GroupID
 , @cur_OddEven
 , @cur_RangeLow
 , @cur_RangeHigh
 , @cur_PostCode1
 , @cur_PostCode2
 , @cur_ID
 , @cur_OldPrimaryID
 , @cur_ThFareID
```

> Error: Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you were consistent in your placement of commas either before or after columns, you might have spotted this:

```
declare cur_range CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
GroupID,
OddEven,
RangeLow,
RangeHigh    --- <-- ******* NO COMMA HERE ******
PostCode1,
PostCode2,
ID,
OldPrimaryID,
ThFareID
```

This is saying `SELECT ... RangeLow, RangeHigh AS PostCode1, PostCode2 ...`